# Declaration element with id and access it in same JSX

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I have dynamically created JSX and 1 element is getting its ID dynamically:

```
{props.types[2].map((element, index) => {
            return (
              <tr key={index}>
                <td className="align-middle">
                  {element.Type &&
                    commonFuctions.splitCapitalLetterString(element.Type)}
                </td>
                <td className="align-middle">
                  <div className="slideThree">
                    <input
                      type="checkbox"
                      value="None"
                      id={element.Type}
                      name="check"
                    />
                    <label htmlFor={element.Type}></label>
                  </div>
                ....
                ....
                ....
```

As you see the element which is getting dynamically id property is the checkbox. Below in the same JSX I have:

```
{/**********************PENSION TYPES***************************************** */}
      {props.types[0].length > 0
        ? DataExtract.uniquePensionTypes(props.types[0]).map(
            (element, index) => {
              {
                console.log(document.getElementById(`${element}`));
              }
            }
          )
        : ""}
    </div>
```

The important part here is this console.log. Argument in getElementById is the same as the id for checkbox. But for some reason it is not discovering the element and it is displaying null. So my questions is why? Is it at all possible to declare id of element and below in the same jsx to access it? I even tried to put static id for this checkbox and below to reach it with it's static value but still not working.

Comment: use state in the component and store all dynamic Ids and use them in other binding from state.

Comment: Are you doing `document.getElementById(`${element}`)` in the same render method?

Comment: @ArpithaChandrashekara Same JSX but other method.

Answer (score 1):

We cannot access the dom elements in the render method. Render just renders the changes on the Virtual DOM and not on the actual DOM.

If you want to access the elements rendered on DOM, do the same in `ComponentDidMount` or `ComponentDidUpdate`.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how this one deserved an upvote, since lifecycle methods have nothing to do with keeping track of changes upon checkbox events. Moreover, (from missing `this` in front of `props` and some other [hints](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-wood-6fg0j)) it is pretty much obvious that OP doesn't use class components (but function ones), so neither *'render method'*, nor lifecycle methods are not relevant here.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `React` `ref` api to access the dom.

> Refs provide a way to access DOM nodes or React elements created in the render method.

The `document.getElementById` is displaying `null` because the html element is not created yet. It's not recommended to directly access `DOM` elements in `React`.

**Example:**

**Class component**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class MyComponent extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <table>
        {props.types[2].map((element, index) => {
          return (
            <tr key={index}>
              <td className="align-middle">
                {element.Type &&
                  commonFuctions.splitCapitalLetterString(element.Type)}
              </td>
              <td className="align-middle">
                <div className="slideThree">
                  <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    value="None"
                    id={element.Type}
                    name="check"
                    ref={this.myRef}
                  />
                  <label htmlFor={element.Type}></label>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          );
        })}
      </table>
    );
  }
}
```

**Functional Component**

```
import React, {useRef} from 'react'

function SomeComponent(props) {
  const inputEl = useRef(null);

  return (
    <table>
      {props.types[2].map((element, index) => {
        return (
          <tr key={index}>
            <td className="align-middle">
              {element.Type &&
                commonFuctions.splitCapitalLetterString(element.Type)}
            </td>
            <td className="align-middle">
              <div className="slideThree">
                <input
                  type="checkbox"
                  value="None"
                  id={element.Type}
                  name="check"
                  ref={inputEl}
                />
                <label htmlFor={element.Type}></label>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        );
      })}
    </table>
  );
}
```

Comment: How can I access this element with the ref in second part of the code?: {/**********************PENSION TYPES***************************************** */}
      {props.types[0].length > 0
        ? DataExtract.uniquePensionTypes(props.types[0]).map(
            (element, index) => {
              {
                console.log(document.getElementById(`${element}`));
              }
            }
          )
        : ""}
    </div>

Comment: Can you add your full component code, or can create codesandbox for this

Comment: Thanks, looking into this.

Comment: I have updated the code,  could you try . https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-aryabhata-8tsn8

Comment: @BorislavStefanov : There's a section in official tutorial about Refs, called [***When to use Refs***](https://en.reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) and none of recommended use cases suits to your problem. Moreover, it states *'Avoid using refs for anything that can be done declaratively'*. Standard approach for that would be follow up selected rows within table component state, using event handlers [lifted](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html#lifting-state-up) one level up. You may check out that approach in action over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60203746/11299053).